# Why does my output file from S3 Glacier return blank even though it says the file is of 20KB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-glacier

I tried to create a multipart upload of my ***Cloudwatch-logs*** to *store it directly in S3 Glacier-vault*. The code which I have attached below ran without throwing any errors. but when I retrieve the output file using the job-retrieval mechanism of S3 Glacier, all I get is an *output file which is blank* (or seems to be blank) but it does say, it has a *storage of 20KB*. I am not sure what is causing this error though I doubt it has something to do with my multipart upload code, so am attaching it below. The process am following is :

1. First creating the buffer from the uploadData. The uploadData is in
   the array format.
2. Calculating the number of parts. I have set the partSize as 32 MB.
3. Calculating the treeHash of the entire data
4. Initiating the upload

```
const multiPartUpload = async (uploadData, logGroupName) => {
  let archiveID = null;
  const archiveDescription = "Trying out multipart upload";
  const partSize = 1024 * 1024 * 32;
  const bufferUploadData = Buffer.from(uploadData);
  let numParts = Math.ceil(bufferUploadData.length / partSize);
  console.log("Nmber of parts ", numParts);
  let startTime = new Date();
  let params = { vaultName: vaultname, partSize: partSize.toString() };
  // hashNode(bufferUploadData).then(console.log());
  let tree_hash = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(bufferUploadData).digest("hex");
  console.log("TreeHash is ", tree_hash);
  // Initiate the multipart upload
  console.log("Initiating upload to", vaultname);
  // Call Glacier to initiate the upload.
  glacier.initiateMultipartUpload(params, function (mpErr, multipart) {
    if (mpErr) {
      console.log("Error!", mpErr.stack);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Got upload ID", multipart.uploadId);

    // Grab each partSize chunk and upload it as a part
    for (var i = 0; i < bufferUploadData.length; i += partSize) {
      var end = Math.min(i + partSize, bufferUploadData.length),
        partParams = {
          vaultName: vaultname,
          uploadId: multipart.uploadId,
          range: "bytes " + i + "-" + (end - 1) + "/*",
          body: bufferUploadData.slice(i, end),
        };

      // Send a single part
      console.log("Uploading part", i, "=", partParams.range);
      glacier.uploadMultipartPart(partParams, function (multiErr, mData) {
        if (multiErr) {
          console.log("Error ", multiErr);
          return;
        }
        console.log("Completed part", mData);
        // console.log("Completed part", this.request.params.range);
        if (--numParts > 0) {
          console.log("in num parts");
          return; // complete only when all parts uploaded
        }
        let doneParams = {
          vaultName: vaultname,
          uploadId: multipart.uploadId,
          archiveSize: bufferUploadData.length.toString(),
          checksum: tree_hash, // the computed tree hash
        };

        console.log("Completing upload...");
        let myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {
          // "Producing Code" (May take some time)
          glacier.completeMultipartUpload(doneParams, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("An error occurred while uploading the archive");
              console.log(err);
              myReject();
            } else {
              var delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
              console.log("Completed upload in", delta, "seconds");
              console.log("Archive ID:", data.archiveId);
              console.log("Checksum:  ", data.checksum);
              archiveID = data.archiveId;
              myResolve();
            }
          });
        });

        myPromise
          .then(function (value) {
            /* code if successful */
            // console.log("Value ", value);
            let arr = logGroupName.split("/");
            let functionName = arr[3];
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              // (*)
              setTimeout(() => resolve(dynamodbPutItem(archiveID, functionName)), 1000);
            });
          })
          .then(function (value) {
            console.log("Here in second promise and archiveID is ", archiveID);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error in promises during completeMultipartUpload ", error);
          });
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are two implementations of Amazon Glacier:

- The original **Amazon Glacier** that uses **vaults and archives**. This is slow and a real pain to use. It is best avoided.
- The **Glacier storage classes** in Amazon S3. They are cheaper than the original Amazon Glacier and can be used via standard S3 API calls. It operates much faster too.

I recommend that you change your program to use **Glacier storage classes** in S3. It will be both cheaper and easier to use.

Comment: I was going to go for the second one but then uploading to s3 and then using a lifecycle rule to transfer the data to Glacier storage classes. That would involve more costs than using Amazon Glacier directly, so I avoided that operation. Because sending it directly to a glacier only involves the uploading cost and downloading cost can be minimized by using the standard export or even lower. Is this not the case?

Comment: The Storage cost is cheaper for S3 storage classes. For example, storing in the **Glacier Deep Archive** storage class is `$0.00099 per GB/month`, whereas 'old-style' Glacier is `$0.0036 per GB / Month/month` (3.5x the price). The Request pricing is confusing, but is not paid often. You can actually **upload directly to the Glacier storage class** by specifying the storage class when performing the upload, so a Lifecycle Rule is not required. AWS doesn't want people to use the 'old Glacier' -- it's actually very difficult to find its [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/glacier/pricing/).

Comment: I am trying to export the cloudWatch logs to s3. I found we could do it with an exportTask command but the command only allows us to specify the s3 bucket and not the storage type of the object. Am I missing something in here?

Comment: Ah! In that case, a Lifecycle Rule would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks though! I was thinking the glacier storage classes occupy more costs.